# How to set up a pipeline for specific branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have a Java project in http://localhost:7990/scm/bout/boutique-a.git
I want to have 2 Jenkins pipeline jobs:

- Job 1/ trigger on commit done on */develop
- Job 2/ trigger on commit done on any */feature
  p
  each job will do a basic mvn install, mvn test, sonar ...

a simple script with

```
    node {
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
     branches: [[name: 'develop]],
     doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
     extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false,
     parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '',
     trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [],
     userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'admin',
     url: 'http://localhost:7990/scm/bout/boutique-a.git']]])
    }
```

works if a commit is done in */develop or if I give explicitly the branch name like feature/test-a but how to configure a script for any feature/*

Comment: I'm sure this article will help you: https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/

Comment: using multibranch pipeline requires to have the jenkinsfile in the project that you want to build (if not in each branch) which is not my case. I want my jenkinsfile to be outside the project

Comment: You must to have this file in the project root otherwise you must to paste your script in the job configuration panel...

Comment: Did you try refs/heads/feature/*

Comment: yes, the job trigger only if i specify feature/test-b

Comment: Have  you tried to use   `when { branch 'development'} ` in your script

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what i'm asking is not possible using pipeline job. 
I found a work arround for "feature/** ". I created a param BRANCH_NAME in the job, then the branch name is send by bitbucket when a push is made on "feature/** " through a basic POST request.

http://user:token@localhost:8081/jenkins/job/MY_JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?token=U1C1yQo7x3&BRANCH_NAME=feature/branche-test